# File download functionality in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I am new to development and trying first time this functionality. I am trying to download the file which is coming from the server as this form
`

```
%PDF-1.2
%����
3 0 obj
<< 
/Linearized 1 
/O 5 
/H [ 760 157 ] 
/L 3908 
/E 3658 
/N 1 
/T 3731 
>> 
endobj
                                                                xref
3 15 
0000000016 00000 n
0000000644 00000 n
0000000917 00000 n
0000001068 00000 n
0000001224 00000 n
0000001410 00000 n
0000001589 00000 n
0000001768 00000 n
0000002197 00000 n
0000002383 00000 n
0000002769 00000 n
0000003172 00000 n
0000003351 00000 n
0000000760 00000 n
0000000897 00000 n
trailer
<<
/Size 18
/Info 1 0 R 
/Root 4 0 R 
/Prev 3722 
/ID[<d70f46c5ba4fe8bd49a9dd0599b0b151><d70f46c5ba4fe8bd49a9dd0599b0b151>]
>>
startxref
0
%EOF
      
4 0 obj
<< 
/Type /Catalog 
/Pages 2 0 R 
/OpenAction [ 5 0 R /XYZ null null null ] 
/PageMode /UseNone 
>> 
endobj
16 0 obj
<< /S 36 /Filter /FlateDecode /Length 17 0 R >> 
stream
H�b``�e``��
```

`
Now in the UI I have did like this

```
downloadFile () {
  api.get(`ips/downloadAttachedFile/` + this.claimId, { responseType: 'Blob' }).then( res => {
    const downloadUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([res]),{ type: "application/pdf" });
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = downloadUrl;
    link.setAttribute('download', 'test.pdf');
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    link.remove();
    URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href)
  })
}
```

when I am trying to download it, pdf is coming as blank file.

I want the data inside that pdf file to be displayed and if I have more type of files like .jpg, .doc etc so how can I download them with their extension. Can anyone help me with this

Comment: you tagged vuejs2 AND vuejs3 - which is it (not that it matters as this has naff all to do with vue) - try commenting out `URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href)` - perhaps revoking the object url too quickly is messing things up

Comment: can you print the `downloadUrl` and use that in a new browser tab to check if the `url` is getting created correctly

Comment: I tried to print downloadUrl and open it in new tab, it is reflecting back me to my homepage. when i download the pdf it shows the exact pages that pdf have but not the data of it @Kaneki21

Comment: commented this line still not worked @JaromandaX

Comment: so it downloads something blank ... completely blank, no content, zero bytes?

Comment: File is blank inside. But the size of file is there like the file I have downloaded is of 1Mb but inside the blank pages @JaromandaX

Comment: did you try `"application/octet-stream"` as the `type` while creating the `Blob` ? [This](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/JavaScript-Save-BLOB-as-PDF-File.aspx) might be helpful

Comment: so, perhaps the file is invalid

Comment: did you try `blob` instead of `Blob` ?

Comment: Yes I have tried "application/octet-stream" still not working @Kaneki21

Comment: Yes, didn't worked @Blackfaded

Answer (score 2):

You could try a timeout after clicking the button.
Works for me.

```
const download = (data, name, type) => {
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data], { type }));
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = url;
  link.setAttribute('download', name);
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.body.removeChild(link);
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  }, 200);
};
```

applied to your case this would be

```
downloadFile () {
  api.get(`ips/downloadAttachedFile/${this.claimId}`, { 
    responseType: 'Blob' 
  }).then(res => {
    download(res, 'test.pdf', 'application/pdf')
  })
}
```

Comment: Still not working

Comment: What the value of res? is it the blob/arraybuffer or is it a nested object?

Comment: I am not sure about your question but it is coming as object ResponseEntity<Object> from backend @Blackfaded

Comment: Have you logged res on your frontend code? I maybe the res object must be called with res.blob()

Comment: I got the answer. Actually all the axios requests are defined in the other file and here we are exporting the api from that file. So I had to define the response type there then it worked.
  if (opts.isBlob) {
      axiosConfig["responseType"] = "blob";
      return axios(axiosConfig).then(response => {
          return response;
      });
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) - works like a charm:

```js
import saveAs from '@/lib/FileSaver.js';
import Axios from 'axios';

Axios.get(`ips/downloadAttachedFile/` + this.claimId, {
  responseType: 'blob',
}).then(response =>
{
  saveAs(new Blob([response.data], { type: 'application/octet-stream' }), response.filename, { autoBOM: false });
});
```